# convert text files(.txt) located in google cloud storage into CSV files?

Tags: csv, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, file-conversion, typeconverter

I have a set of text(.txt) files in cloud storage(that are uploaded into the Cloud storage in every 5 minutes). What I want to do is I want to upload them into big query. But bIgquery cant accept text files. So I have to convert it to Bq acceptable format. What is the best possible way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data#supported_data_formats), BigQuery only supports loading data with the following file format: CSV, JSON, Avro and Google Cloud Datastore backups.

Hence, if you upload a Text file to BigQuery, BigQuery reads your text file as a CSV file and then really would run into an error.

You would have to manually convert your text file into a CSV file, before uploading it to BigQuery.

Alternatively, you may also [use Cloud Dataprep as it supports text files as inputs](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Supported-File-Formats_57344528). You may do transformations with your text file here in Dataprep then export the results to BigQuery.

Here is an [Overview of Dataprep](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/) and a [Quickstart Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-dataprep) to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet:

```
def getBlobAsString(bucketName, blobName):
    storageClient = storage.Client()
    bucket = storageClient.get_bucket(bucketName)
    blobFile = bucket.get_blob(blobName)
    blobStr = blobFile.download_as_string()
    return(blobStr)

def getBlobAsFile(bucketName, blobName, txtStr):
    storageClient = storage.Client()
    csvFileName = blobName.replace('txt', 'csv')
    bucket = storageClient.get_bucket(bucketName)
    blob = bucket.blob(csvFileName)
    blob.upload_from_string(txtStr)
    return(csvFileName)
    
txtBucket = "bucket-name"
txtBlob = "blob-name"

# Read text file content as string
txtBlobAsStr = getBlobAsString(txtBucket, txtBlob)
txtStr = str(txtBlobAsStr, 'utf-8')

# Write text file content to CSV file
csvBlob = getBlobAsFile(txtBucket, txtBlob, txtStr)
```