# Convert TXT file into CSV with Cloud function and populate data in Google BigQuery

Tags: python, csv, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, txt

I am trying to convert a txt. file into a csv. and populate a BigQuery table with all data through a Google Cloud function.

The TXT file looks pretty similar to a CSV file, it looks as below. The entire file weight is around 35Go with more than 350k rows.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I tried to apply the python script shared above but it didn't work... My function is running properly but it doesn't populate any data to BigQuery.

I followed this [stackoverflow tread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63190843/convert-text-files-txt-located-in-google-cloud-storage-into-csv-files/66326021?noredirect=1#comment117259314_66326021).

My main.py function:

```
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery

def txt_to_csv(event, context):
    fileName = "gs://Bucket_name/file.txt" 
    bigqueryClient = bigquery.Client("project-name")
    tableRef = bigqueryClient.dataset("Dataset").table("07_02_2021")
    dataFrame = pd.read_csv(fileName, sep=",")
    bigqueryJob = bigqueryClient.load_table_from_dataframe(dataFrame, tableRef)
    bigqueryJob.result()
```

My requirements.txt file:

```
google-api-core==1.16.0
google-api-python-client==1.8.0
google-auth==1.12.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
google-cloud-bigquery==1.24.0
google-cloud-core==1.3.0
google-cloud-storage==1.26.0
google-resumable-media==0.5.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.51.0
pandas==1.0.3
pyarrow
```

**Is there someone to help me?** I feel I am missing a step to make it work correctly... like maybe for example [creating a specific dataframe/schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-create-table) for my table? Or maybe should I [load a pandas dataframe to a table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pandas-gbq-migration#loading_a_pandas_dataframe_to_a_table) or is it the wrong way?

Comment: You are not "converting a txt file into a csv", you are telling pandas that your txt file IS a csv.  Is your file actually in CSV format?

Comment: Hi @TimRoberts my file in GCStorage is a TXT file and I want to convert it into a CSV. I thought "pandas.read_csv" was an efficient function to do it, isn't it? What would you recommend? Thanks!

Comment: We can't possibly know, because you haven't shared a single thing about what UserData.txt actually contains.  Show us a few lines and we will advise you.

Comment: @TimRoberts I have updated my question with a screenshot of the TXT file.

Comment: That is a CSV file.  pandas should be able to read it.  Have you already created a schema for your bigquery table?  Are you sure it matches the columns in your CSV?

Comment: Yes the BQ table schema is 13 columns with STRING data. I put STRING for all value for test purpose, to be sure my file populates the table, but take account that some data are  actually Timestamp or Integer value.

Comment: Then what's the question?  Your question doesn't say anything about what works and what doesn't, or what goal you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I was successfully able to populate the data from a file in **Cloud Storage** bucket using your code:

```
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery

def txt_to_csv(event, context):
    fileName = "gs://Bucket_NAME/File.txt" 
    bigqueryClient = bigquery.Client("PROJECT_ID")
    tableRef = bigqueryClient.dataset("DATASET_NAME").table("TABLE_NAME")
    dataFrame = pd.read_csv(fileName, sep=",")
    bigqueryJob = bigqueryClient.load_table_from_dataframe(dataFrame, tableRef)
    bigqueryJob.result()
```

I followed the next steps:

**1) I used a .txt file with the following data:**

```
full_name,birth_year
"Lea",1996
"Jose",1995
"John",1997
"Berta",2001
"Marta",2005
```

**2) I created a Table in BigQuery with the following fields:**

- full_name as String
- birth_year as Integer

**3) I deploy the Cloud Function using the requirements.txt you provided, it deployed successfully however when I tested the Cloud Function** `"By going to your Cloud Function --> Testing Tab and click on **Test the Function **button` ", I got the following error:

```
Missing optional dependency 'gcsfs'. The gcsfs library is required 
to handle GCS files Use pip or conda to install gcsfs.
```

- To mitigate this issue, I added the [gcsfs](https://pypi.org/project/gcsfs/) library to the Cloud Functions requirements.txt file:

```
google-api-core==1.16.0
google-api-python-client==1.8.0
google-auth==1.12.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
google-cloud-bigquery==1.24.0
google-cloud-core==1.3.0
google-cloud-storage==1.26.0
google-resumable-media==0.5.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.51.0
pandas==1.0.3
pyarrow
gcsfs==0.7.2
```

**4) I deploy the function again and tested. This time the function added the data correctly to the BigQuery Table.**

### **Solution**

- So please Note: Deploying the Cloud Function will not populate the data into BigQuery, you will need to test it.
- On the other side, you have a table with fields as String Type but in the .txt file,you have data of type Integer, timestamp etc. If you just want to test then you can put all the data in your .txt file as strings or change the field type of your BigQuery Table according to the data type you have in the file.

Comment: thank you very much I wasn't able to answer sooner ! Yes actually the problema I had was related to the txt file which came up with lot of wrong formated data...